# How to solve the issue of getting more data within a map function

Tags: reactjs, promise, pouchdb, map-function

I am new to reactjs and pouch db.

I am building a table row for which the data comes from 2 local database in pouchdb

As I am iterating through a map function I would need to query another database based on the id value and use the data from the queried document to use in the table cell I am constructing

```
       tableRows = this.props.mytools.db1.rows.map(mytool => {
                    this.props.dispatch(asyncFetchfromdb2(mytool.id));
                    mytool.type=this.props.mytools.db2.type;
                    return (
                        <tr key={mytool.id}>
                            <td> {mytool.information}</td>
                            <td>{mytool.type}/></td>

                        </tr>
                    );
                });
```

Any help is appreciated.

Please suggest if there is a better approach to fetch value from 2 different pouchdb to show in a table row where few cells use value from db1 and others use value from db2.

Comment: You can't use `.map()` for your iteration if you want the iteration to wait for your async results.  I don't understand enough of what you're trying to do to know what to suggest.

Comment: I am building a rows of data based on the number of tools i have. Each tools has more information stored in an array, but then I use the tools id to get some more data from another database that matches the id. So in a single row the data is coming from 2 database for the same tool id